# SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function date_format(date, unknown) does not exist

Tags: laravel, postgresql, pg-query

I created this to compare is time now the same as time in my table row executes_at.

```
$dateNow = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
$hourNow = Carbon::now()->format('H');
$minuteNow = Carbon::now()->format('i');

$recordings = Recording::with('therapy')
        ->where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(executes_at,'%Y-%m-%d')"), '=', $dateNow)
        ->where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(executes_at,'%H')"), '=', $hourNow)
        ->where(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(executes_at,'%i')"), '=', $minuteNow)
        ->get();
```

and it worked in MySQL but because now we use PostgreSQL I have this error

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function
>   date_format(date, unknown) does not exist

can somebody help me with this.

Comment: Instead of `date_format` try using `to_char` E.g.: `to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD')`, Formatting Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be simplified. Just generate the proper datetime format (without minutes) and use `DATE_TRUNC()` to compare it:

```
$dateNowToMinute = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$recordings = Recording::with('therapy')
    ->where(DB::raw("DATE_TRUNC('minute', executes_at)"), '=', $dateNowToMinute)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, I just changed this ```'Y-m-d H:i'``` and it worked.